# Refreshing URL with JSF ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf-2, browser-history

I'm using JSF 2 with PrettyFaces and also the `<h:link>` and `<f:param>` tags extensively to get bookmarkable pages (It's great to finally forget about all those POST request in a JSF application).

However, some of these links only changes a small part of the page (mainly when the user stays in the same view), so it's nicer to send ajax requests instead. However, `<f:ajax>` cannot be used with `<h:link>`, just `<h:commandlink>`. I can send parameters many ways with a commandlink as well, but in this case the URL stays the same after the request. So it becomes out of sync with the content of the page, and it's not refreshable.

I've seen sites that use links that send kind of a mixture of GET and ajax requests (pointing to a new url while modifying the page with ajax), but so far I haven't found any solution.

Can I somehow refresh the url with jsf after the ajax request finishes (or when the user clicks)? Or do I have to use some external JS library?

**EDIT**: The JS library that is needed here is the new JavaScript History API. [More info.](http://html5doctor.com/history-api/)
I guess JSF does not use this API currently. But I'm still interested in this issue from a JSF developer's point of view.

Also, is it planned for a future release of JSF? Combining `<f:ajax>` with `<h:link>` would be a perfect solution.

Comment: I've looked at it some months ago for OmniFaces. This is unfortunately not cheap/trivial. The very same changed URL should be able to return exactly the desired JSF view state including all ajax changes as performed by postbacks by a single plain GET request. All the necessary information to achieve this in an application-wide (session-independent) manner makes the GET URL very lengthy. There are ways to shorten the URL, but still... And then I'm not taking component library specifics into account yet.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I don't completely understand it, though. I think it should be the developer's responsibility to set a URL that gives exactly the same page back when refreshed - the views should handle the request attributes etc. Actually I've already done that, since `<h:link>` generates a non-ajax GET link - I all want is to send an ajax request instead and set the URL to the one previously generated by `<h:link>`. It could be `<h:commandLink>` or anything else as well, the point is that it should work like this.

Comment: If the purpose is pure page-to-page navigation, then it would indeed be simpler to implement. But the `<f:ajax>` is generally been used for many other more useful things than just navigation. *That* part is then not trivial.

Comment: I just realised that I had misunderstood a really important part of the story. If the action method of my commandlink returns anything than null (or void), the whole page will be reloaded, no matter if I use `f:ajax` or not. So navigating to a different view is not possible with an ajax request and response. Am I right? Then my question loses most of its sense. What did you mean by "`<f:ajax>` is generally been used for many other more useful things than just navigation"? If I'm correct it cannot be used for navigation.

Comment: @BalusC I don't know if you read my previous comment (I'm new here), if you didn't, could you?

Answer (score -1):

`<f:ajax>` has attribute **onevent**. It takes name of `javascript` function which will be called after `ajax request` successfully finishes. So it is possible to add js function which will navigate to required url after ajax call finishes. Something like:

```
        <h:commandLink id="testButton"
                       value="Test">
            <f:ajax event="action"
                    execute="@form"
                    render="@none"
                    listener="#{myBean.testButtonClickedHandler}"
                    onevent="navigate"/>
        </h:commandLink>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function navigate() {
        window.location.href = "required url";
    }
</script>
```